# Can not clear marker in Mapbox GL

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

When I clear all marker I have error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lng' of undefined

My code:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    });

var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker().addTo(map);
marker.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the marker somewhere by lng and lat. Which you didn't set.

Here's an [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker) from MapBox Documentation Page.

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
   .setLngLat([30.5, 50.5])
   .addTo(map);
```